How best to install LLDB on Windows 11?
I am setting up to compile and debug C++ in a Windows 11 VM running on an Apple silicon machine.
Answering this post, @NeoZoom.lua warns:
FYI: if you're macOS Apple Chip users then GDB will not work for you. Use LLDB instead.
Okay, I have gcc and related tools installed via MSYS2 on my Windows. Indeed, gdb crashes. So I would like to install LLDB - but I got lost in this page and can't figure out from the documentation which of these items to install to get LLDB. Or is there a package manager approach that would be more recommended?

The comment you are referring to is about using GDB on macOS runninng on ARM, since GDB does not support that OS/platform combination. You are running Windows on ARM, so this is not related. The fact that GDB crashes for you is most probably a separate problem.
